# Intercom PHP variables breaking script

Tags: php

I have some variables I'm trying to insert into intercom parameters:

```
<?php
$user_id = "1234";
$intercom_name = "example";
$intercom_email = "example";
$intercom_name = "example";
$company_id = "example";
$company_name= "example";
?>

    <script>
    window.intercomSettings = {
    app_id: "XYZ123",
    id: "<?php echo $user_id; ?>",
    name: "<?php echo $intercom_name; ?>",
    email: "<?php echo $intercom_email; ?>",
    company: {
        id: "<?php echo $company_id; ?>",
        name: "<?php echo $company_name; ?>",
      }
    };
    </script>
```

However using php variables in this way seems to break the script, does anyone know why?

Comment: That looks like it should work just fine. Sure does https://jsfiddle.net/nu4eaphe/

Comment: @user1419810, both code in same script/file?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good but alternatively you can try with json_encode() for initialize object in javascript into php

```
<?php
$object=array(
    "app_id"=>"XYZ123",
    "id"=> "1234",
    "name"=> "example",
    "email"=> "example@example.com",
    "company"=> array(
        "id"=> "example",
        "name"=> "example",
    )
);
?>

<script>
window.intercomSettings = <?php echo json_encode($object); ?>;
</script>
```